# Notepad++ has stopped working

Tags: wine, mint, notepad-plus-plus

I am new to Linux, having previously been a Windows-only user. I installed Notepad++ two months ago and everything has been working fine. Then, out of the blue, today it has stopped working and will not longer open when I either click on the desktop icon or try to run it out of the terminal.

```
<UserName>@<MachineName:~$ notepad-plus-plus 
Installing application.. 
Running hook '/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/sommelier/hooks/pre-install' 
Starting application.. 
wine: cannot find L"/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/dosdevices
/z:/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus.exe"
```

- Note 1: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Notepad++ without success.
- Note 2: I installed Notepad++ both originally and today using Snap.

Can anyone please explain to me what is going on and how I can fix it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

My OS version:

- NAME=Linux Mint
- VERSION=20.3 (Una)

Comment: Linux Mint is off topic on AU

Comment: Same is happening on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and just solved it according to this post:
https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17192/npp-on-usb-for-unix/5 (see Meta Chuh's answer)

```
cd "/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/common/.wine/dosdevices
/z:/home/<UserName>/snap/notepad-plus-plus/363/notepad-plus-plus/"
rm -rf *
wget https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.4/npp.8.4.portable.x64.zip
unzip npp.8.4.portable.x64.zip
mv notepad++.exe notepad-plus-plus.exe
```

Afterwards running `notepad-plus-plus` would work :)

Comment: Saved my day, but lost the history , anyway cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, switched to notepadQQ and notepadNext (reimplimentation of notepadd++) and haven't been happier. (every time snap updates, the path breaks)